# Java CLI : Cant parse arguments

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons

I am trying to parse command line arguments as

```
Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("c", "count", false, "number of message to be generated");
        options.addOption("s", "size", false, "size of each messages in bytes");
        options.addOption("t", "threads", false, "number of threads");
        options.addOption("r", "is random", false, "is random");
        CommandLine cli = new DefaultParser().parse(options, args);

        int count = Integer.parseInt(cli.getOptionValue("c", "20000000"));
//        int count = Integer.parseInt(cli.getOptionValue("c", "100"));
        int recordSize = Integer.parseInt(cli.getOptionValue("s", "512"));
        int threads = Integer.parseInt(cli.getOptionValue("t","4"));
        boolean isRandom = Boolean.valueOf(cli.getOptionValue("r", "true"));
        System.out.println(" threads "+threads);
        System.out.println(" count "+count);
```

and i run it in eclipse with

```
t 6 c 7
```

but i always get

```
threads 4
count 20000000
```

what am i missing?

Comment: same result. still does not work

Comment: You passed in `false` for all of the options you are adding. That parameter is whether the option takes an argument, which for all but the random one, I'd say would be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `true` for `addOption` method when the option takes an argument. From the Javadoc:

> - @param hasArg flag signally if an argument is required after this option

```
    options.addOption("c", "count", true, "number of message to be generated");
    options.addOption("s", "size", true, "size of each messages in bytes");
    options.addOption("t", "threads", true, "number of threads");
    options.addOption("r", "is random", false, "is random");
```

Yes, and a leading `-` is required for short option specification (e.g. `-t 4`) and a leading `--` is required for long option specification (e.g. `--threads 4`).

Comment: thanks! that did it. after that i still had to specify as -t=6

Comment: When I specified in the IDE the program arguments as `-t 6 -c 200` it seems to work.